# What is the best way to use the database connection file in PHP?

Tags: php, html5

I have a connection.php file into my root folder and at the bottom, I added `BASE_URL`

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username='root';
$password='';
$db='demo';


$charset = 'utf8mb4';
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
  }
  
define('BASE_URL', 'http://example.com/');
?>
```

Now, On each file, I am adding the connection.php file

```
<?PHP 
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/connection.php');
?>// HTML code start
```

Is this the correct way to use the database connection file? What should I use `include` or `require`?

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Although the connection code itself is good, some improvements can be made.

### A separate config file

When your code goes live, most likely database credentials will be different from those at home. Therefore, having them hardcoded in the script will make it extremely inconvenient. Instead, create a separate file for your configuration as follows:

- add the `config.php` line in `.gitignore` (in case you are not using git yet, you definitely should)
- create a file called `config.sample.php` with all variables set to empty values like this:

  ```
    return [
        'db' => [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'dbname' => '',
            'port' => 3306,
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        ],
        'base_url' => 'http://example.com/',
    ];
  ```
- **add** it to the version control
- then in your application bootstrap file have a code like this:

  ```
    <?php
    if (!file_exists('config.php'))
    {
        throw new \Exception('Create config.php based on config.sample.php');
    }
    $config = require __DIR__.'/config.php';

    define('BASE_URL', $config['base_url']);

    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $dbconf = $config['db'];
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$dbconf[host];dbname=$dbconf[dbname];charset=$dbconf[charset]";
    try {
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
    }
    unset($dbconf, $config['db']);
  ```
- then, as suggested, create `config.php` on the every server that your application runs, each with its own set of values.

### Actually using the connection

Just use this `$pdo` variable. When PDO is needed in a function - then pass it as a function parameter. If some function do not need PDO but it calls some other function that needs PDO - then pass `$pdo` into both. Yes it seems a bit a nuisance but this way you will always know what's going on and where. Avoid using dirty tricks like declaring variable `global`, singletons and such.

### Some minor issues

- closing PHP tag is not necessary and [forbidden](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#2-general) by the standard
- `// HTML code start` reveals completely wrong approach to structure the code. Never an HTML code should start from the very beginning. Your PHP code should perform all the data manipulations first, and only then start the output
- `require` should be always used for the files that are vital for the application. As this file surely is, then it must be require'd. Note that you should avoid using `require_once` and the likes - nowadays it's not more than a dirty hack to cover an inconsistent code

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have some doubts. 1)  As of now I am not using git. Do I need to create .gitignore file in my root folder and add a file called config.php? 2) Where I can get the version control? 3) bootstrap file? Do you mean to say connection.php file? 4) How my config.sample.php will call? You haven't added anywhere

Comment: 1. No but you should start. 2. git is the version control. 3. Yes. Looks like you are using connection.php as one, but it's already misleading: you have BASE_URL defined in this file which has nothing to do with connection. and there will be other unrelated to connection but required in the every other file code blocks. So it's better called bootstrap than connection. 4. Not sure what you mean. it is called in the code above.